# Place image icon on image map and make it clickable using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am relative new to JavaScript. We have floor plan image and we need to place a seat image on office floor plan and make it clickable.
We need to display certain information like seat no, vacant or occupied, Name of the person if it is occupied etc. on mouse over event or on clicking. I tried with image map functionality but unable to place icon on the image map.
Please help me on this issue.

```
<img id="feature" src="trignometry-page-001.jpg" border="0" width="1754" height="1240"  orgWidth="1754" orgHeight="1240" usemap="#image-maps-2014-10-19-105116" alt="" />
<map name="feature">
<area  alt="" title="" shape="rect" class="group" coords="228,560,250,585"  target="_self" onClick="alert('hi')" data-maphilight="{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.6}"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="1752,1238,1754,1240" alt="Image Map" style="background-color: transparent;border: 1px solid yellow;" title="Image Map"  />
</map>
```

Comment: would help a lot if you could share some code that you tried... you know the drill, you don't seem to be new to SO ;)

Comment: Why is this tagged `jquery-ui`..?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some javascript events will help you to understand more how this works.
http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events

And you can check this canvas sample for multiple areas, this is using Jquery.

https://github.com/neshte/jquery-canvas-area-draw

It would be better to have the code you are using for this.

Hope this helps.